# SSRS: Nvarchar value not showing in tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

This is my query for the `tablix` values:

```
SELECT     id,Value, DateSaved, Comment
FROM       RB_Values
WHERE     (DateSaved IS NULL AND @DateSaved IS NULL OR
                      DateSaved = @DateSaved)
```

In my `tablix` there are 2 columns: `Value` and `Comment`. I get `Value` with this expression: `=Fields!Value.Value` and `Comment` with: `=Fields!Comment.Value`.

When I preview the report I can see the `Value` but not the `Comment` values. Is it because `Value` is `int` and `Comment` is `nvarchar(max)`? Or is something else?

**EDIT**

I added a new tablix in my report without any formatting and again I can see `Value` but not `Comment`. Query works as expected and returns `Comment`

Tablix:

[image: tablix image]

Query Designer result:

[image: query designer result]

Comment: When you run your query with the same parameters in the report is there anything returning for the comment?

Comment: @NewGuy In query designer I run the query and I get the comment value correctly

Comment: Have you done any formatting to the cell where you placed the Comment Field?

Comment: @NewGuy No, in `textbox properties` -> `General` I have : `Name:Comment`, `Value:[Comment]`

Comment: Can you post an image of your tablix?

Comment: @NewGuy check updated post please

Comment: If the comment has any HTML tags present it might not be rendering correctly. If you do have HTML tags, right click the comment placeholder in the designer and then properties, then choose HTML as the Markup Type